Differentiable structures on homeomorphic spaces
I'm reading these notes on differential geometry, and it has the following passage on page 14:
Deep Result 2.19. Let $(M_1^m,\ \hat{\mathcal{A}}_1)$, $(M_2^m,\ \hat{\mathcal{A}}_2)$ be two differentiable manifolds of class $C^r$ and of equal dimensions. If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are homeomorphic as topological spaces and $m\leq 3$ then $(M_1^m,\ \hat{\mathcal{A}}_1)$ and $(M_2^m,\ \hat{\mathcal{A}}_2)$ are diffeomorphic.
It seems to me like the existence of two differentiable structures on $\mathbb{R}$ (for instance, those given by $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x^3$) seem to contradict 2.19, since the underlying topological spaces are both $\mathbb{R}$ and trivially homeomorphic. Where am I misunderstanding things? Are these differentiable structures somehow diffeomorphic through some map other than the identity map?

Indeed those two manifolds are diffeomorphic. The identity map is not smooth, but there is a diffeomorphism between them. (Hint: it’s staring you in the face!)

@WhileIAm So $f:M_1\to M_2, \ x\mapsto x^3$ is a diffeomorphism? And its inverse is smooth because it descends to the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$ under the charts on each?

It depends on what your $M_1$ and $M_2$ are, but yes. You should check this directly using the definition.

Unreal, thanks!
